# Determine the limit for $a\geq-1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $s_n(a)=1^a+2^a+\cdots+n^a$ where $a$ is real. Determine:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n(a+1)}{ns_n(a)}$$

for $a\geq-1$.

I can show that it converges. I can also find the limit for particular case when $a=0$. I think I could find a formula for natural numbers and prove it by induction. But since $a$ is real, I am stuck. Any tips of how should I proceed? Thanks!

Comment: Hint: this sum is approximated by the integral.

Comment: you mean by $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{s_x(a+1)}{xs_x(a)}dx$ ? but it gets bloody messy, doesn't it?

Comment: Does the limit exist when $a=-1$?

Comment: it's $0$. but how could that help me?

Comment: @Sarunas No. Just approximate the sum $s_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for $a>-1$,
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k\leq n} k^{a+1}}{n\sum\limits_{k\leq n} k^a}
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k\leq n} (\dfrac{k}{n})^{a+1}}{\dfrac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k\leq n} (\dfrac{k}{n})^a}
=\dfrac{\int_0^1 x^{a+1} \mathscr{d}x}{\int_0^1 x^a \mathscr{d}x}
=\dfrac{a+1}{a+2}$.

for $a=-1$,
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{\sum\limits_{k\leq n} k^{a+1}}{n\sum\limits_{k\leq n} k^a}
=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n}{n\sum\limits_{k\leq n} k^{-1}}=0$

So, for $a\geq 1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n(a+1)}{ns_n(a)}=\dfrac{a+1}{a+2}$

Comment: just as tetori suggested in the comments. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From [this](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/mathematics/series/sumGeneralPowersNaturalNumbers.htm), $$s_m(a)=O\left(\frac{m^{a+1}}{a+1}\right)$$ (This is also evident from the examples [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html)) for $a\ge 0$

So, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s_n(a+1)}{ns_n(a)}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n^{a+2}}{a+2}+\text{ terms in the lower powers of $n$}}{n\{\frac{n^{a+1}}{a+1}+\text{ terms in the lower powers of $n$}\}}$$
$$=\frac{a+1}{a+2}$$